# How to make replace() global in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this question had been asked lot of time but i could not find solution. I have some smilies which each of them has code to be rendered as smiley using replace() , but I get syntax error, I don't know why and how to render my code `:/` to smiley

```
txt = " Hi :/ ";
txt.replace("/\:/\/g","<img src='img/smiley.gif'>");
```

Comment: Can you post the error as it's written please?

Comment: `txt.replace` does not modify `txt`, you need to assign the result to a variable - `txt = txt.replace(/:\//g,"<img src='img/smiley.gif'>");` also note the unquoted literal RE.

Comment: IMO you should think about doing smiley the same way as github (`:disappointed:`) instead of (`:/`) because it has less chance to happen in a normal text (think about url `http<img src='img/smiley.gif'>/google.com` is no good)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in the first argument of [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) it escapes the wrong characters and it uses a string that seems to contain a `regex` instead of a real [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

The second line should read:

```
txt.replace(/:\//g,"<img src='img/smiley.gif'>");
```

`/:\//g` is the `regex`. The first and the last `/` are the `RegExp` delimiters, `g` is the "global" `RegExp` option (`String.replace()` needs a `RegExp` instead of a string to do a global replace).

The content of the `regex` is `:/` (the string you want to find) but because `/` has a special meaning in a `RegExp` (see above), it needs to be escaped and it becomes `:\/`.

Answer (score 9):

Your regular expression doesn't need to be in quotes. You should escape the correct `/` forward slash (you were escaping the wrong slash) and assign the replacement, since [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't modify the original string.

```
txt = " Hi :/ ";
txt = txt.replace(/:\//g,"<img src='img/smiley.gif'>");
```

Based on [jonatjano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637223/how-to-make-replace-global-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment90239090_51637223)'s brilliant deduction, I think you should add a little more to the regular expression to avoid such calamities as interfering with URLs.

```
txt = txt.replace(/:\/(?!/)/g,"<img src='img/smiley.gif'>");
```

The above ensures that `://` is **not** matched by doing a [negative-lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead).